# How to represent implementing Interface in Activity Diagram

Tags: android-activity, interface, uml

I am beginner in UML and now I am creating one activity diagram to represent interfaces . How can I draw for implementing Interface in activity diagram.

Comment: your question is *how to represent a class in an activity diagram* (whatever that class realizes the interface), the answer is  : you cannot. An activity can just be the behavior of an operation of that class,  but an operation is not the class

Answer (score 0):

An interface will appear as activity parameter like so:

[image]

The parameter to the left is typed with the interface. It can send/receive objects which are defined by the interface via object flow to action(-pin)s inside the activity. That's basically all you need.

Note that I show the interface only for illustration. There is usually no need to include it along with the activity on your AD.

Comment: @bruno Well, of course the question is quite vague. I'm not going to spend much effort in an answer unless the OP shows effort himself. If so and the mist clears up I can either improve or delete my answer. Let's see. (I flagged the comments since I noticed them and comments are not meant for disussions, you know.)